# PHP rename file path error

Tags: php, jquery, file, unix, server

I'm building a web app with HTML/PHP/JS/MySQL and I use the following php code to move files from one directory to another. This script is called via a JQuery AJAX POST request.

```
function move($img, $t){
global $qID;
$path="";
$qPath=dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."\questionData\questionImages";
$aPath=dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."\questionData\answerImages";
$ePath=dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."\questionData"."\\"."explanationImages";
if($t=="QI") $path=$qPath;
else if(strpos($t,'A') !== false) $path=$aPath;
else if($t=="EI") $path=$ePath;
if(rename (dirname(__DIR__)."\uploads\\".$_SESSION['qSessionID']."_".$t.".png", $path."\\".$img.".png")) return true;
else return FALSE;}
```

This works perfectly on my local machine where I run XAMPP package on Windows 8.1 but gives an error that says no such file or directory in the UNIX server from 000webhost.com which I use temporary.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest you changing slashes as *nix use the other ones, and on windows machines php works perfectly fine with the other type

Comment: Please use the PHP constant [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) instead of slashes or backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/` instead of `\`

```
function move($img, $t)
{
    global $qID;
    $path="";
    $qPath=dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."/questionData/questionImages";
    $aPath=dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."/questionData/answerImages";
    $ePath=dirname(dirname(__DIR__))."/questionData"."/"."explanationImages";
    if($t=="QI") $path=$qPath;
    else if(strpos($t,'A') !== false) $path=$aPath;
    else if($t=="EI") $path=$ePath;
    if(rename (dirname(__DIR__)."/uploads/".$_SESSION['qSessionID']."_".$t.".png", $path."/".$img.".png")) return true;
    else return FALSE;
}
```